# Rails Googlemaps Draw and Save Polygons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, google-maps, heroku

Using Rails and Googlemaps V3, I'm looking some advice (before i head off down the wrong path) for the best approach to build the functionality to:

1) draw a polygon that describes a geographical area
2) capture and save the polygon data to the db (postgres)
3) make a query that will tell me if a point is inside the polygon or not

As far as i can see from examples that are out there - the polygon drawing bit is fairly doable but i'm not clear how to capture that data, and in which format i should save it (i see postgres has a polygon data type...). Also for the query, i'm not sure how to go about making that happen - does postgres have any magic that can make this happen (we're using heroku).

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this too. Although I'd prefer to use mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In general your options depend in part on scale.  If this is a flat, plane map, the best approach would be a polygon and point approach.  This would work best for things like city maps.

For a global map you probably want to use PostGIS's geometry and geography types since they are more flexible.